# Getting segfault in qt5serialport.dll with PyQt and signals

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, pyqt, access-violation, qtserialport

I'm currently struggling with a weird segfault I'm getting when using QSerialPort and emitting a signal, with Windows XP SP3, Python 3.3.3 and PyQt5 5.1.1.

I really wonder if this happens in pure Qt with C++ as well, but my C++ is horrible and I don't have a running toolchain set up.

Minimal example code (sorry, couldn't manage to simplify more):

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot, QIODevice, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtSerialPort import QSerialPort

PORT = 'COM59'

class DVIFlasher(QObject):
    ser = None
    flash_done = pyqtSignal(int, int)

    def __init__(self):
        super(DVIFlasher, self).__init__()
        self.ser = QSerialPort(PORT)
        self.ser.readyRead.connect(self.read)

    def flash(self):
        print(self.ser.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite))
        self.ser.setBaudRate(115200)

    def read(self):
        print("Got data")
        self.ser.close()
        self.flash_done.emit(0, 0)

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Widget, self).__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton("Start", self)
        self.flasher = DVIFlasher()
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.flasher.flash)
        self.resize(self.btn.sizeHint())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Widget()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When I run this and receive a byte via the serial port, I get an "Access violation" (aka segfault) in qt5serialport.dll. Sometimes it happens when clicking "Start" the first time, sometimes after the second time.

Some things I observed so far:

- The signal needs to have a bool/int as first parameter, and some other parameter -- otherwise it doesn't seem to trigger.
- When I emit the signal *before* the port has been closed (`self.ser.close()`), it doesn't seem to trigger.
- On Linux (Archlinux, Python 3.3.2, PyQt 5.1.1) I can't reproduce this, but after starting a second time, I always get `QSocketNotifier: Invalid socket specified`.

What gives? Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in [Py]Qt somewhere?

Comment: I wonder if you had solved this? If not, can you provide a backtrace for the crash with debug symbols included?

Comment: @LaszloPapp I worked around it by doing `ser.close()` after emitting the signal. Someone here mentioned it might be a specific Qt bug (and it seems very similiar), but his comment is gone now... I have no idea how I could install Qt/PyQt with debug symbols and get a trace under Windows, but I suspect it won't be too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing [this bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-33938). This is a relative old issue and known. If we are lucky, it can be fixed for 5.2.1. Your workaround about not calling `ser.close()` in the `readyRead` signal handler looks reasonable.

Hope, this helps.

Comment: I **do** call `ser.close()` in my signal handler, just at the very end, that seems to work.

Comment: @TheCompiler: please do not do that. It currently has undefined behavior, mostly identified as crash.

Comment: You're right, after some refactoring I now get "... .exe funktioniert nicht mehr" (literally "does not work anymore", but not sure what the english message is). But when I set a flag in the slot and close the serialport with a QTimer from my MainWindow, the same thing happens! No time to gather more information right now, but will try after the holidays.

Comment: @TheCompiler: OK, have a nice rest.

Comment: Nevermind -- it *does* work with a QTimer from the MainWindow, I just forgot to actually remove the `ser.close()` from the slot.